# Set SecurityContextToken to SOAP Header

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, cxf, soap-client

I build my java classes with wsimport. On first soap request I get a SecurityToken. In other Request I must put this Token to header. How can I do this?

I nothig found in web.

```
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
            <wsc:SecurityContextToken>
                    <wsc:Identifier>__TOKEN__</wsc:Identifier>
            </wsc:SecurityContextToken>
    </wsse:Security>
```

---

If I set the Header by Example. I get following Exception. Any Idea?

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: SAAJ0120: Can't add a header when one is already present
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Can't add a header when one is    already present.
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.addHeader(EnvelopeImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.addHeader(EnvelopeImpl.java:94)
at client.header.WSSUsernameTokenSecurityHandler.handleMessage(WSSUsernameTokenSecurityHandler.java:47)
at client.header.WSSUsernameTokenSecurityHandler.handleMessage(WSSUsernameTokenSecurityHandler.java:15)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeHandleMessage(HandlerChainInvoker.java:347)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeHandlerChain(HandlerChainInvoker.java:254)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainInvoker.invokeProtocolHandlers(HandlerChainInvoker.java:132)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:169)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.access$000(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:71)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor$1.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:81)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor$1.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:78)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
at $Proxy36.getWSR(Unknown Source)
at client.WSClient.main(WSClient.java:160)
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the framework you use on the client side. One example how to do that can be found [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-header-part-1-client).